# Deactivating Xamarin.Android through Visual Studio Online build

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a build to build a Xamarin.Android project. I have a step to activate the license and another step to deactivate it. The deactivation fails with the error

> Failed to deactivate license, only license activated by this task can be deactivated.

I think I am at an invalid state due to other problems I ran into before. How can I force a deactivation? Maybe a command line? I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the build with `Debug=true` I noticed the Activate step was creating a `License` file under `/Users/username/Library/MonoAndroid`. Deleting that file solved the problem